# CUDA-Multiforcer will not work although CUDA Toolkit and everything is installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda

I installed everything [like here](http://www.dickscheid.net/2011/10/19-cuda-ubuntu-1110/) on my new Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop.

Specifications:

- Intel core i5 2500k,
- 16 GB RAM,
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560TI CU II by ASUS

So I installed everything but the CUDA-Multifocer says:

```
This program requires a CUDA-capable video card.
No cards found.  Sorry.  Exiting.
```

The output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
    jan@hadabanana:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri May 25 19:14:53 2012       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.49   Driver Version: 295.49         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  GeForce GTX 560           | 0000:01:00.0  N/A    |       N/A        N/A |
|  22%   42 C  N/A   N/A /  N/A |  27%  276MB / 1023MB |  N/A      Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.           Not Supported                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
jan@hadabanana:~$
```

Comment: What is your `nvidia-smi` output?